# References missing from Clickonce Publish Application FIles section

Tags: clickonce

I have  winforms project that references many third party controls but when i go to the Application Files under Settings -> publish -> Application Files..they are not listed!  I have the the reference set to Copy Local=True but still no luck..has been working fine for years untill now...its laso happening to another project.  Any suuggestion?

Answer (score 0):

(I already answered this in the MSDN Forums.) The Infragistics controls have to be installed in the GAC. They don't show up in Application Files because your current project references them in the GAC.

Comment: so if i reinstall Infragistics..should this fix it?

Comment: You need to install it on the client machine. If you haven't changed anything about your deployment, or updated to VS2010, ClickOnce wouldn't magically remove your files. Check the references in your application in Visual Studio and look at the path -- where do they point to? Probably to the GAC. For files to show up in Application files, they must be added locally to the project.

Comment: I've updated the thread in the MSDN Forums. Here's the link for those who are interested: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/fcb2008b-e442-4c49-aa7a-0acb1ef0e210